# Reserved word javascript "this"

Tags: javascript

I was reading a school book for AJAX for J2EE and I found some instructions about JavaScript that I can't understand. And it is the reserved word "this", I know what means it in java for example. but in this script I can't understand.

Maybe its a stupid question, but if one of this bigger community can help me I'll be grateful.

Instruction:

```
var objPunto;
objPunto = {
      x:10, y:40, dibujar: function(){
                           alert(this.x + "," + this.y);
                                     }
}
```

I don't know which is the reference for these "this".

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

this in javascript is slightly complicated but your example is probably the most simple.

this refers to the parent, so in your example this.x is referring to objPunto.x

upon calling objPunto.dubujar() you would get the alert 10,40